# How do I enable BPG decoding in ownCloud?

Tags: owncloud, bpg

ownCloud does not display [BPG](http://bellard.org/bpg/) images by default, offering to download them instead.

How do I add BPG support to ownCloud using the [decoding JavaScript](http://bellard.org/bpg/bpgdec.js)?

Answer (score 1):

The slideshow component of the Files app is actually contained in a 3rd party app and it needs to support the format for you to be able to view those files.

Gallery has an issue to track the implementation of the format
https://github.com/owncloud/galleryplus/issues/185

You won't be able to see thumbnails in the Files app, but you'll be able to view those files when clicking on them.